# "What does 'Method is not applicable for arguments' mean?

Tags: java, sorting

I am supposed to `read strings from a text file and sort them (alphabetically)`.
The text files include string names like Tory Warren, Guy Cowan. I am able to read all the strings (names) from the file. However, they are all unsorted.I have tried to use `collections.sort`. Unfortunately, it wouldn't work. Can you please help me with that one?

Here is my error trace:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method sortNames(String) in the type ProcessNames is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>)
```

And my code:

```
public ArrayList<String> sortNames(String filename) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(filename);
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        names.add(scan.nextLine());
        Collections.sort(names);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
    scan.close();
    Collections.sort(names);
return names;
}
```

My Test Unit:

```
void testSortNames() {
    Collections.sort(namesMatchFile1);
    assertArrayEquals(namesMatchFile1.toArray(), processNames.sortNames(namesReadFile1).toArray());

    Collections.sort(namesMatchFile2);
    assertArrayEquals(namesMatchFile2.toArray(), processNames.sortNames(namesReadFile2).toArray());

    Collections.sort(namesMatchFile3);
    assertArrayEquals(namesMatchFile3.toArray(), processNames.sortNames(namesReadFile3).toArray());

    Collections.sort(namesMatchFile4);
    assertArrayEquals(namesMatchFile4.toArray(), processNames.sortNames(namesReadFile4).toArray());
```

I am new to Java and literally just started a few weeks ago! So please be kind.
Thank you loads for your help.

Comment: From the error it looks like you are trying to send in a list of names, not a filename. You have not posted the calling code though.

Comment: I think that I am reading from a txt which has been provided for me

Comment: I have edited my post and put down the Test Unit Code

Comment: Still missing the types for `namesReadFile1` ect.

Comment: Hello Taronus, welcome to Stack Overflow. The core of your problem is not sorting an ArrayList, but a runtime error that you don't understand. Please re-formulate the question title accordingly (e.g. "What does 'Method is not applicable for arguments' mean?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. You aren't calling the method correctly.

I made a local file at `/tmp/test.txt` containing this:

```
300
200
400
500
100
```

Then I copied your `sortNames()` method exactly as you posted it and ran it with the following (where `Scratch` is the name of the class I used):

```
try {
    new Scratch().sortNames("/tmp/test.txt");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your code correctly sorted and printed the contents of the file:

```
100
200
300
400
500
```

Comment: This is the content of one of my txt files : 
Hiram Mcfarland
Clark Snow
Tory Warren
Guy Cowan
Ned Mcintosh
Hugo Johnston
Beth Bates
Tiffany Mccarty
Kevin Matthews
Elisabeth Yates
................
But what do you mean by me not calling the method correctly?

Comment: You posted this as one of your test examples as a way to call the "sortNames()" method: `processNames.sortNames(namesReadFile1).toArray()`. The variable `namesReadFile1` is not valid input to that method – that is, `namesReadFile1` is not a `String` but instead a `ArrayList<String>` (from the error message), so you are trying to "run" or "call" your `sortNames()` method but you aren't passing the correct data type for that method. Your definition of `sortNames()` says it accepts one "String" argument, so that's what you must give it when calling that method.